# asp:Checkbox ticking is prevented using jquery but OnCheckedChanged event is still fired

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

asp.net checkbox **OnCheckedChanged** is fired, however it shouldn't be fired on click as i have prevented it using jquery's functions **e.preventDefault()** and **e.stopPropagation()** and used **return false** too. It has stopped ticking of checkbox but it continues to fire checkbox 'OnCheckedChanged' event.

In Detail: On checkbox click first i have to open one dialog box asking user to select for yes or no option. If user selects yes only then checkbox should be checked and 'OnCheckedChanged' event of asp.net should be fired. But here in my case it is running on both.

**Code Behind**

```
protected void chkTaskStatus_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //code here
}
```

**Jquery code below**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Div_Tasks input:checkbox').click(function (e) {
        //get the checked element
        var $this = $(this);
        var chkboxId = $this.attr('id');

        // ask for yes no option
        $.SmartMessageBox({
            title: "<i class='fa fa-times txt-color-white'></i> Are you sure??",
            buttons: '[No][Yes]'
        }, 
        function (ButtonPressed) {
            if (ButtonPressed == "Yes") {
                $("#" + chkboxId).prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }    
});
```

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) say "The CheckedChanged event is raised when the value of the Checked property changes between posts to the server.". Was the checkbox checked the last time you posted to the page? If it was but now it's empty, then that sounds like the documented behaviour. Just a guess though.

Comment: checkbox was not checked at all, It works fine according to me and jquery did it very well, but 'CheckedChanged' event is fired. This is the whole problem, why that asp CheckedChanged event is fired??, when the checkbox is not ticked. btw thanx for consideration buddy :)

Comment: i've already tried it. but not succeeded. :(

Comment: What happens if you take out the jquery completely and use the checkbox as you normally would? Is it still triggered when it should not be?

Comment: nop, not triggered when it is unticked

Comment: hey DelightedDOD, are you still there??

Comment: The only other thing I can think of would be to change your code to `if (ButtonPressed == "Yes") {
     $("#" + chkboxId).prop('checked', true);
}
else{
 $("#" + chkboxId).prop('checked', true);
 $("#" + chkboxId).attr('checked', true);
}` but looking at it, it doesnt look like that would be the issue.

Comment: i figured it out buddy. 'chkTaskStatus_Changed' event is also a small piece of code of javascript (that fire the event from client side), which runs before that (above mentioned) jquery function. so, I changed my way of code now. thanx for your concern brother. :)

Comment: glad you got it sorted, happy coding